# How to list all supplementary groups for unix user using c++

Tags: c++, unix, usergroups

I am trying to find a way to get a list of all groups a unix user has access to. I want to be able to pass either the unix username or the uid of a user to a c++ program as an argument and then return a list of groups that this user has access to.
I have done some reading about this and as far as I can see this can be achieved using getgroups() but I can't find an example of how to do this by passing in a particular username or uid to getgroups. All the examples I have found seem to just display all the groups for my user account or whoever is the effective uid of the person running the program.
Please can you help me with how I can do this?

I can get all the user account info from struct passwd and am able to pass argv[1] which is a unix users username and pass this to getgrgid:
(getpwnam_r(argv[1], my_passwd, pwdbuffer, pwdlinelen, &tempPwdPtr)) != 0)
I just don't know how to use the value of argv[1] and find out all the groups a unix user has access to using getgroups

Answer (score 2):

Use `getgrouplist(3)` function, it does exactly what you want. It expected username so if you want to list all the groups user with given UID is part of, you need first to translate UID to username with help of `getpwuid_r(3)` function.

Comment: Thanks Anydot, just one more thing if you or anyone might be able to help. Whenever I try to use the function getgroups list I just can't get my program to compile. It keeps saying "error: 'getgrouplist' was not declared in this scope"

Comment: I have looked at the following example and instead of using the value "user" I am changing this to argv[1] and passing username as argument but still it errors with "error: 'getgrouplist' was not declared in this scope" http://homepages.cwi.nl/~aeb/linux/man2html/man3/getgrouplist.3.html#lbAH

Comment: Infact any example code that I can find where getgrouplist is used they all wont compile and come back with the same error saying its not declared. Is there something I am missing here? I am including grp.h aswell

Comment: Please can someone help me. I am getting really stuck with this as I don't know why its saying this when it is already declared within that scope

Comment: Make sure you are doing `include <grp.h>` and in case you are compiling in c99 mode or something like that, make also sure that macro `_BSD_SOURCE` is defined before this `include`

Comment: Just tried to compile with this set and I am still getting that error saying getgrouplist was not declared

Comment: for this you are missing lot of information, like exactly which unix are you using, what are the compiler flag and compiler etc. And that is so much information that you should start new question for it.